# running total count in pivot chart

Tags: excel, graph

I am having troubles creating a pivot chart.
This is how my pivot table currently looks:

```
Row Labels   |   Count of New Interfaces
apr/12       |   3
may/12       |   1
dec/12       |   2
```

I would like to create a graph that shows me the running total of interfaces during a period. I would like to see a line graph that has a horizontal axis for the months and a vertical axis for the total number of interfaces.

For example:

- For apr/12, I would see the number 3
- For may/12, I would see the number 4 (because there is 1 extra new interface)
- For dec/12, I would see the number 5 (because there are 2 new interfaces added).

Does anyone have an idea how to configure the pivot graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should that be 6 for December?

1. In your pivot table, you go to Sigma values, where you should currently have Count of Interfaces.
2. Go to Value Field Settings -> Show Values As tab -> Running Total In
3. Select the variable that you are using as your row label (i.e. Months).

Then you can choose the type of Pivot Chart that you would like by clicking on the ribbon.

[image: Screenshot]